# Regex to replace certain characters with JQuery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an input that searches a database with jQuery autocomplete. It's working well but I want it to be more permissive with some characters. Let's say in the database the data is : **oc-5** I need the requested string **oc5** or **oc_5** to match the current string in the database.

Same if the current value in the database is **ac2**, I need **a-c-2** or **ac_2** or **ac-2** or **ac 2** to match the value.

Actually, I want the characters "-", "_" and " " to act like a wildcard.

I guess I have to regex my *request.term* but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here's my code :

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({  

    delay: 100,
    source: function (request, response) {

        // Suggest URL
        var datatype = this.element.attr('data-type');
        var suggestURL = href+"&datatype="+datatype+"&term="+request.term;

        // JSONP Request
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: suggestURL             
        })
        .success(function(data){
            response(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you can replace characters using `.replace()` like so: `request.term.replace(/[-_\s]/g, "");`. This replaces every occurrence of a hyphen, underscore, or space with an empty string.

Comment: You will not be able to do this in the request itself. It will need to be done on the server. Since you're sending the request to the server and getting a listing back in success, the Query is performed on the server. That is where you need to break down the request and make it hit the specific items that are in the DB.

Comment: Thank you @Souleste. This would work but partially. I also need the request to match  inversely. Ex: if the data in the DB is **oc-5**,  I need the request oc5 to match the data too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to go both ways, you could check if the two values match after using a replace, if so make the request value equal the database value.

*where `db_val` is your database value and `rq_val` is the sent request value.*

```
if (db_val.replace(/[-_\s]/g, "") == rq_val.replace(/[-_\s]/g, "")) {
    rq_val = db_val;
}
```

If you don't want to allow one of the listed special characters at the beginning or end of the string, and you don't to allow multiple special characters in a row, you could rather use this regex: `.replace(/^(?:[^-_\s][-_\s]?){3}(?<![-_\s])$/, "")`. This means check for any character excluding the specials followed by a special repeated three times, and makes sure the end of the string is not preceded by a special.

I'm not great at regex but that's what I came up with.

Comment: This looks like the way to go! I only need to find a way to implement it to my ajax function. Thanks @Souleste for your time!

Comment: @HugoLaporte Do you know what the database value is before you run the ajax function? Is that what `datatype` is?

Comment: @HugoLaporte You could run that if statement, and if false throw an error popup and prevent the ajax from running. Or you could run the ajax and do the test on the server, returning an error if false. - tried to edit my other comment but it was too late.

Comment: datatype is used to select my column name in my DB table

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
  delay: 100,
  source: function(request, response) {
    // Suggest URL
    var datatype = this.element.attr('data-type');
    var term = request.term;
    // Example: 'a-c-2' or 'ac_2' or 'ac-2' or 'ac 2'
    term = term.replace(/(-|_|\s)/g, "");
    // Result: ac2
    var suggestURL = href + "&datatype=" + datatype + "&term=" + term;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: suggestURL
      })
      .success(function(data) {
        response(data);
      });
  }
});
```

You can update the Term before sending it and remove any of the `"-"`, `"_"`, or `" "` characters from the string with `.replace()` using a Regular Expression.

Working Example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var term = $("input").val();
    console.log(term.replace(/(-|_|\s)/g, ""));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Search: <input type="text" /> <button>Test</button></p>
```

Comment: Thank you Twisty for your answer! Very appreciated. But I guess it would work only if the value in my database doesn't contain any "-" "_" or  space. Let's say the data is **"ac-2"** in the database and im typing **"ac2"** or **"ac_2"**. Is there a way to make it match the value ? Thanks again!

Comment: @HugoLaporte not directly possible unless there is a specific format to the dat in your DB. if it's always CC-# then you could easily reformat the Term to match before sending it.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Twisty I can format the data in the DB but how I would make the request return "ac-2"? I can not change these document codes for the user. Second column with a formated string ?

Comment: I would remove any strange characters as I did, and then create a new string. `var nStr = term.slice(0,2) + "-" + term.slice(2,1);` This will turn `ac2` into `ac-2`. Now this will break when more characters are entered by the User.